# Reading Realm object by ID using rowID

Tags: react-native, realm

I am trying to access my realm object by the number parameter. Can I use a rowID as a filter for my query, or is there another way to query a value based off the parameter?

Here is my realm object

```
class Hole extends Realm.Object {}
Hole.schema = {
  name: 'Hole',
  properties: {
    number:  'int',
    fullStroke: 'int',
    halfStroke: 'int',
    puts: 'int',
    firstPutDistance: 'int',
    penalties: 'int',
    fairway: 'string'
 },
};
```

Here is my query within the renderRow method.

```
{realm.objects('Hole').filtered('number = {realRowID}').fullStroke}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String interpolation should be `` `id == ${i}` `` (Use backtick and `${}`). Your query should be:

```
realm.objects('Hole').filtered(`number = ${realmRowID}`)
```

Queries return `Results` object. `Results` is similar to `Array`. `Results` is a container that contains the objects of query results. So `Results` doesn't have `fullStroke` property because it isn't `Hole` object. So you should retrieve an element from `Results` first.

For example use `[0]` to retrieve first element as same as `Array`

```
realm.objects('Hole').filtered(`number = ${realmRowID}`)[0].fullStroke
```

See also https://realm.io/docs/react-native/latest/#queries